# Resize image inside div

Tags: css

I currently have an image that is larger than a containing div where the div has a width of 70px and a height of 45px.

What I am trying to do is horizontally/vertically center the image inside the div, and resize the image while keeping the aspect ratio.

When resizing the image, if the width side is larger than the height, resize the image so that the image height is the div's height, and hide the width overflow after centering.

If the images height side is larger than the width, resize the image so that the width matches the divs width, and hide the height overflow after vertically centering.

Aspect ratio must be maintained when resizing the image.

If the images height and width are smaller than the div, center the image with the div and its done.

Here is an image giving an idea of what I am trying to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm9jy.png

I know I can do this using javascript or a jquery plugin, but is there anyway to do this using CSS?

If so, how would I go about it?

What I have so far:

```
.container
{
    position: relative;
    height: 45px;
    width: 70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #111;
}

.container img
{
    display: block;
    max-height: 45px;
    max-width: 70px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqwVJ/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a JSfiddle? It's hard to visualize.

Comment: Let me do a fiddle, one sec.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zqwVJ/

Comment: Here is an image giving an idea of what I am trying to accomplish: http://i.imgur.com/hQjUsJA.png

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtxcX/6/)

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var $height = $(this).height();
    var $width = $(this).width();
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $height -= $parent.height();
    $width -= $parent.width();

    if($height < $width){
        $(this).height($(this).parent().height());
        var $width = $(this).width();
        $width -= $parent.width();
        $(this).css('margin-left',-1*( $width/2));
    }
    else{
        $(this).width($(this).parent().width());
        var $height = $(this).height();
        $height -= $parent.height();
        $(this).css('margin-top',-1*( $height/2));
    }

});
```

**note**: don't forget about `div { overflow:hidden; }`

Answer (score 1):

If your image is a background image, this can be done easily.

```
<div style="width: 70px; height: 45px;
    background-image: url(http://placehold.it/30x30);
    background-color: #ddf; background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat">
</div>
```

If it isn't, you will probably need JS.

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/CjNEc/

Comment: This is the *right* answer. A background image would be the elegant answer so if the OP is able to refactor, the style above is the best solution. But if the image is a foreground image done with an <img> tag, there's no way outside of JS to tell the image to change its size based on its parent. Only background images can do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is dynamic, I would use background-size and an inline background-image :

**HTML**

```
<div style="background-image:url(image-source.jpg);></div>
```

**CSS**

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

Comment: it is image not background

Comment: @AndreFuentes you probably want `contain` instead, since OP wants it to maintain aspect ratio but be all visible.

Comment: @Mohsen i think it's not possible to do that with <img> only with css.
maybe you can use your image with a inline background style: 

<div style="background-image:url(imase-source.jpg)"></div>